# Declaring 2D integer array at specific memory location with C

Tags: arrays, c, beagleboneblack

I am writing in C on a BeagleBone Black MCU.
I need to create a 2D unsigned int array to store some collected analog data from two sensors.
Currently I have individual unsigned int arrays for each sensor's data but I'd like to change this to have one variable that is 2 dimensions with one dimension being the sensor the data originated from.

Here's what I have so far and it works just fine. (Apologies if this isn't formatting correctly.  I tried to bold the code but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome the way I'd expect.)

```
#define SHARE_MEM 0x10000

#define E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE 200

volatile unsigned int *DetTSampleSet = (unsigned int *) SHARE_MEM;

volatile unsigned int *DetBSampleSet = (unsigned int *) (SHARE_MEM + (E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int)));
```

I believe this code ensures that DetBSampleSet is located immediately after DetTSampleSet with no overlap.  It works fine.  I am able to use these variables like this.

```
int pnr;

for (pnr = 0; pnr <10;pnr++)

{

// do some stuff to get RawAnalog from sensor T.

DetTSampleSet[pnr] = RawAnalog;

// do some stuff to get RawAnalog from sensor B.

DetBSampleSet[pnr] = RawAnalog;

}
```

What I want is this.

```
int pnr;

for (pnr = 0; pnr <10; pnr++)

{

// do some stuff to get RawAnalog from sensor T (0)

DetSampleSet[0][pnr] = RawAnalog;

// do some stuff to get RawAnalog from sensor B (1)

DetSampleSet[1][pnr] = RawAnalog;
```

I think I can just declare this as the first variable in this memory space like this.

```
#define SHARE_MEM 0x10000

#define E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE 200

volatile unsigned int *DetSampleSet = (unsigned int *) SHARE_MEM
```

If I do then, I don't think I have to worry about how this data is actually structured in memory as in

are the first four bytes DetSampleSet[0][0] and the next four bytes DetSampleSet[0][1] or DetSampleSet[1][0] because I don't plan to access this data with any pointers/addresses?

However, if I want to declare another variable in memory adjacent to this variable with no overlap, do I just double the size offset like this?

```
volatile unsigned int *NewIntVariableAfterFirstOne = (unsigned int *) (SHARE_MEM + (E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE * 2 * sizeof(unsigned int)));
```

Thanks for any and all help and your patience as I'm getting back into C after nearly 30 years.

I appreciate the comments and answers.  I've tried to post a response but it seems I can't comment at length but have to add to my original question.  So here goes...

So, I readily admit to getting lost sometimes in the declaration of pointers like this.  The original code I posted works fine.   I need to declare multiple variables in this memory space so my primary concern is to declare them properly so as to not overwrite one.  Basically, ensure the start of the next variable declared is past the end of the one declared prior.   So, for example, if the pointer to integer variable A is to be used as a 1-D array of X elements, then X*sizeof(int) should be a safe start of the next variable, say integer variable B.   Right?  And if I want to use variable A as an array to be accessed as a 2-D array, then I would just do 2*X*sizeof(int) to get the start of the next variable after A, right?

Comment: The right thing would be to define a separate section in a linker script in the memory address you want to place your data in, and then use `__attribute__((section("name")))` (or equivalents for other than gcc compilers) with your array declaration.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   Could you direct me to a resource that I can use to help me set this up?  I probably used to do this in my sleep 35 years ago but I'm just getting back into this work and I'm really rusty.  I'd like to try this but just need a bit more to guide me through it.  Thanks!

Comment: I afraid I don't have any comprehensive resource I could recommend. The info is just scattered around. @0 gave you an example in his answer though.

Comment: Understood.  I have the reference manual from Texas Instruments for this processor's toolchain.  I'll ask them for some help too.  Fingers crossed.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that it is a valid and appropriate thing in the first place, according to your C implementation, to create a pointer value in the way you are doing, what you need is a to declare your pointer as a pointer to an array, and cast appropriately:

```
#define SHARE_MEM 0x10000

#define E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE 200

volatile unsigned int (*DetSampleSet)[E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE] =
        (unsigned int (*)[E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE]) SHARE_MEM;
```

You should then be able to access the block by doubly indexing `DetSampleSet`, just as you say you want, with all the values for `DetSampleSet[0]` laid out in memory contiguously, and immediately preceding those for `DetSampleSet[1]`.

Comment: I would avoid additional variable as it requires two additional memory reads on the ARM targets. https://godbolt.org/z/MbsKE4q3G

Comment: That's probably good advice, @0___________, but for this answer I stayed as close to the OP's original code as possible to keep the focus on the question posed.

Comment: You could simplify the code a bit by casting to `void*` rather than quite long pointer to array type. Or even `#define SHARE_MEM ((void*)0x10000)` similar to how `NULL` is typically defined as `(void*)0`

Comment: @0___________  it is enough to add extra `const` to avoid extra memory read:
`volatile unsigned int (* const DetSampleSet)[E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE] = ...`

Comment: @tstanisl it is still using memory without any need.

Comment: Yes, @tstanisl, or I could have used a `typedef` as 0___________ did in their answer.  I chose the more verbose approach presented here largely for didactic purposes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, adding extra casts is not a good practice. `SHARE_MEM` is kind-of typeless anyway. It's a bit like casting result of `malloc()` which should be avoided except keeping compatibility with C++

Comment: @tstanisl, it's not a question of extra casts.  There's only one either way; it's just a question of which one.  The example presented here demonstrates the type name that corresponds exactly to the variable's type.  As a bonus, this translates directly to C++, too, whereas the `void *` alternative does not.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest to use when accessing hardware fixed size integers

You can use the pointer to array:

```
#define SHARE_MEM 0x10000

#define E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE 200

typedef int32_t buff[E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE];

#define DetSampleSet ((volatile buff *)SHARE_MEM)

//example usage

int32_t foo(size_t sample, size_t sensor)
{
    return DetSampleSet[sensor][sample];
}
```

`#define` is used to avoid unnecessary memory reads.

https://godbolt.org/z/c45rKvvvh

EDIT. The comments have changed the requirements. You need to change linkerscript.

1. Add memory area (length gas to be set by you as I do not know how bit it is):

```
MEMORY
{
     /* the stuff which was already here */
     SHAREDMEM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000, LENGTH = 32M
}
```

In the sections add new section

```
.shared_mem_section (NOLOAD):
{
    shared_mem_section_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.shared_mem_section))
    KEEP(*(.shared_mem_section*))  
    shared_mem_section_end = .;
} > SHAREDMEM
```

2. In your C code:

```
unsigned __attribute__((section(".shared_mem_section"))) DetSampleSet[NSENSORS][E_RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Comment: Sorry to be slow responding...I was fortunate enough to get some nice R&R recently.

Comment: I need to declare multiple variables in this memory space so my concern is to declare them so they don't overlap. Basically, ensure the start of the next variable declared is past the end of the one declared prior.  For example, if the pointer to integer variable A is to be used as a 1-D array of X elements, then Xsizeof(int) should be a safe start of the next variable, say integer variable B. Right? And if I want to use variable A as an array to be accessed as a 2-D array, then I would just do 2X*sizeof(int) to get the start of the next variable after A, right?

Comment: Looking at this another way, the dimensions don't really matter.  What matters is that the memory allocated is sufficient.  So if I declare variable A starting at 0x10000 and going for 1024 bytes and an int is 4 bytes, then I can store 1024/4 ints in that space.  I can choose to use a 1-D array of 1024/4 elements or a 2-D array of 1024/(4*2) elements, right?

Comment: @WalterCEden see EDIT (in 15 minutes).